# Retrieving last commit ID / revision number from a deployed application

Tags: c#, java, c++, git, svn

I would like to have a function returning the last revision / commit ID of the source from which the deployed application / library was built.

I have been using the `__DATE__` and `__TIME__` macros in C++ but this approach has obvious drawbacks.

**What tools are available to achieve this in an automated manner?**

I am using Eclipse-CDT for C++ (Linux, SVN) but it I am also interested in git solutions, and sources written in Java and C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were working with a Makefile and SVN, you could do something like this for C or C++:

```
REVISION=$(shell svnversion)
CFLAGS=... -D__REVISION__=\"$REVISION\"
```

I'm not that familiar with CDT, but I understand it's able to use a Makefile-based build system.

Comment: do you know if something similar is possible for Git?

Answer (score 3):

By using Visual Studio and C# you could within a Pre-Built step calling the [`SubWCRev`](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-subwcrev.html) command with a template file, that will be copied to a file used within the solution.

The command within the Pre-Built step is:

```
<PreBuildEvent>SubWCRev "$(ProjectDir)\" "$(ProjectDir)VersionProvider.template.cs" "$(ProjectDir)VersionProvider.cs"</PreBuildEvent>
```

Within the project add the following two files:

```
<Compile Include="VersionProvider.cs">
  <DependentUpon>VersionProvider.template.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<None Include="VersionProvider.template.cs" />
```

With this content:

```
internal static class VersionProvider
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides the current subversion revision number
    /// </summary>
    internal const string CurrentSVNRevision = "$WCREV$";
}
```

Last but not least within AssemblyInfo.cs add the following line:

```
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion(VersionProvider.CurrentSVNRevision)]
```

The project will by this way automatically get the current subversion revision number of this project folder baked into version info of the application which can be seen on the details page of the file properties.

You can also retrieve this information through code at runtime:

```
private string GetAdditionalVersionInfo()
{
    var assembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
    var attributesFound = assembly.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute), true);

    var version = attributesFound.OfType<AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();

    return version != null ? version.InformationalVersion : String.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 /// <summary>
 /// Gets the SVN date.
 /// </summary>
 /// <value>The SVN date. value</value>
// ReSharper disable UnusedMember.Global
public static new string SvnDate{
  // ReSharper restore UnusedMember.Global
  get {
    const string S = "$Date$";
    return S.Substring(7, 19);
  }
}
 /// <summary>
 /// Gets the SVN ID.
 /// </summary>
 /// <value>The SVN ID. value</value>
// ReSharper disable UnusedMember.Global
public static new string SvnID{
  // ReSharper restore UnusedMember.Global
  get{
    const string S = "$Id$";
    const string D = "$";
    return S.Replace(D + "Id: ", string.Empty).Replace(" " + D, string.Empty);
  }
}
 /// <summary>
 /// Gets the SVN rev.
 /// </summary>
 /// <value>The SVN rev. value</value>
// ReSharper disable UnusedMember.Global
// ReSharper disable MemberCanBePrivate.Global
public static new string SvnRev{
  // ReSharper restore MemberCanBePrivate.Global
  // ReSharper restore UnusedMember.Global
  get {
    const string S = "$Rev$";
    return S.Item(1);
  }
}
 /// <summary>
 /// Gets the SVN author.
 /// </summary>
 /// <value>The SVN author. value</value>
// ReSharper disable UnusedMember.Global
public static new string SvnAuthor{
  // ReSharper restore UnusedMember.Global
  get {
    const string S = "$Author$";
    return S.Item(1);
  }
}
```

Note S.Item(n) returns a space delimited zero based item. Replace with your own code. Also, new is only necessary to deal with inheritance. Props must be set in svn. I dont have a snippet showing the expansions since I am on Mercurial now.